# Calling PowerShell script inside guest VM with PowerCLI Invoke-VMScript

Tags: powershell, powercli, vcenter

Inside my guest VM, I have a PowerShell script that does some automation. However, I am trying to invoke that PowerShell script from outside using PowerCLI (inside PowerShell). Currently, my script works but instead of "running" the PowerShell script inside the guest VM, it opens it as a text file instead. Also, inside the guest VM, there is a interactive services detection that pops up when I call the below script. How can I resolve these issues?

```
add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core 

Connect-VIServer 192.168.1.29 # connects to vCenter 

$vm = Get-VM -name 'CentOS 7'
$script = '"C:\Automation\StartServices.ps1"'
Invoke-VMScript -vm $vm -ScriptText $script -GuestUser 'user' - GuestPassword 'password' -ScriptType Powershell
```

Comment: Do you try to start a powershell script on cent os?

Answer (score 1):

Use single, or double quotes for your `$script` path but not both:

```
$script = 'C:\Automation\StartServices.ps1'
```

This seems to be the only issue. Tested & working in my `PowerCLI` environment.

Comment: That helped, the script now works but on my guest VM, the interactive services detection screens pops up and isolates the automation in another environment. I disabled interactive services detection by going to services.msc and disabling that but then when I run the script, nothing happens (I expect a program to open and some clicking to occur)

Comment: @ennha1 `Invoke-VMScript` does not run applications / programs in the foreground with a UI. It is used to execute scripts remotely in the background. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hmm. I may have been under the wrong impression then. I have a PowerShell script that I want to run. However, that PowerShell script does a number of things - opens a program, calls another macro function that does some clicking.

Comment: @ennha1 I don't think that's possible with `Invoke-VMScript`. For example if you use: `Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText { Start-Process notepad.exe } -VM ...` a process will start in the background, but notepad will not open. You can confirm this using `Get-Process notepad` on the remote machine.

Comment: I tried that exact thing, by opening up notepad or calc.exe. All those programs open in the background (where the interactive display comes up) so it is sort of in its own isolated environment but not in the foreground. Does that seem right?

Comment: @ennha1 On my machine a process starts running in the background, but the interactive GUI (calculator, notepad editor) is not shown in the foreground.

Comment: Correct, those applications (calc, notepad) are in the background, right?

Comment: Well in the background -  a process is running but the application is not visible on the desktop.

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I see. Thanks for letting me know this limitation of Invoke-VMScript

Comment: Any option you got to run the apps in the foreground using powercli?